# Apigee Usergrid | migrating data between applications

Tags: apigee, usergrid

Is there any standard migration process to move data collection+entities from one application to an other within the same org of usergrid?

Answer (score 1):

There currently is no out of the box tool to use for data migrations.  One approach would be to retrieve your initial collection page by page and save the entities to disk in JSON format.  Then, you can load the entities in bulk to your new app using HTTP POST.